# Convertir Map a POJO

Tags: java

Tengo un map como el siguiente : `Map<MiObjeto, List<OtroObjeto>>` y lo quiero convertir a un POJO que está definido de la siguiente manera :

```
public class UnObjetoMas {

private MiObjeto miObjeto;
private List<OtroObjeto> otrosObjetos;

    //Getters and setters

}
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esa conversión?

Answer (score 2):

Un map completo no se puede convertir en ese POJO, en todo caso se podria convertir en un Collection, por ejemplo un List, para lo que podrías hacer algo así:

```
List<UnObjetoMas> list = new ArrayList<>();

for(Map.Entry<MiObjeto, List<OtroObjeto>> e : mapa.entrySet()){
    list.add(new UnObjetoMas(e.getKey(),e.getValue()));
}
//suponiendo que existe un constructor en la clase UnObjetoMas
public UnObjetoMas(MiObjeto miobj,List<OtroObjeto> otros){
    this.miObjeto = miobj;
    this.otrosObjetos = otros;
}
```

Por decirlo de otra manera, tu clase UnObjetoMas representa un Entry del Map pero no esta diseñada para representar un Map completo.
Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Existen varias opciones, una es mediante [Jackson](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/), usando la clase [ObjectMapper](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_objectmapper.htm) y su método [convertValue](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jackson/jackson_objectmapper.htm):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
MyPojo pojo = mapper.convertValue(myMap, UnObjetoMas.class);
```

Comment: Pero tengo entendido que mapper.convertValue toma los valores del map como los atributos del POJO y, es decir, itera entre cada key y cada atributo, por lo cual solicita que el valor del map sea un String y su contenido sea igual al de un atributo de mi Pojo, por lo tanto esa opción no funcionará para mi caso.